# Change permalinks for posts & for custom post types

Tags: posts, permalinks

I need to change blog post permalink to `/post/post-title` & I want to remove "custom-post-type" slug from the custom post type so that `/custom-post-title` will be shown.

These two doesn't work with each other, I can either remove custom-post-slug with rewrite or I can add post to blog-post with permalink in settings. I even tried PHP codes to do same, but didn't work.
How can I get desired output? Already tried rewrite slug for CPT & `with_front=false`.

Answer (score 0):

`with_front=false` is the key, but WordPress also seems to like to hard-cache the settings you originally register a CPT with. Try `unregister_post_type()` above the CPT registration so it's completely removed and immediately added again from scratch with the `with_front` setting.